# Specific format of Array of Strings

Tags: vb.net, matlab

I have an OpenFileDialog and its multiselect is set to true. What I want is to store the OpenFileDialog.FileNames of each images in an array of strings in this kind of format:

```
images = ['C:\Program Files\sample1.jpg';'C:\Program Files\sample2.jpg']
```

I'm new to VB, and I badly needed this for my project. I hope you can help me how can I do it.

PS: The reason why I need that kind of format because I integrated my MATLAB functions to VB and that is the kind of format that MATLAB needs.

Comment: `OpenFileDialog.FileNames` is already a `string()` with all selected paths. So what is your desired result, a `string` in this format or a `string()`(as mentioned)?

Comment: What I want is to store the image's locations in this kind of format:
images = ['C:\Program Files\sample1.jpg';'C:\Program Files\sample2.jpg']

Comment: or how can I make a string with this kind of format:
`['location1' ; 'location2'; location']`

i mean that whole thing above is a single string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use LINQ and `String` methods:

```
Dim paths = From path In openFileDialog1.FileNames
            Select String.Format("'{0}'", path)
Dim images = String.Format("[{0}]",  String.Join(";", paths))
```

Comment: Is the value of the images in this kind of format?
`['C:\Program Files\sample1.jpg';'C:\Program Files\sample2.jpg']`

Comment: Its a single string in this format, yes. Although i could not test it because I'm writing on a mobile phone.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim aStringArray As String() = {"test", "test2", "test3", "test4"}
Dim fullString As String = ""

For Each s As String In aStringArray
    fullString &= String.Format("'{0}' ; ", s)
Next

fullString = String.Format("[{0}]", fullString.TrimEnd(" ; ".ToCharArray()))
```

Comment: How can I change the "test", "test2", etc to the image locations from OpenFileDialog.FileName ?